# Does anyone know (or remember) how breaking class laws could cause problems in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Some time after I asked [What happens to you if you break the monad laws?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399648/what-happens-to-you-if-you-break-the-monad-laws) I stumbled across this unexplained phrase on Haskell Wiki, on a page about [Safely running untrusted haskell code](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Safely_running_untrusted_Haskell_code):

"creating class instances that violate assumed laws (cf EvilIx)"

as an example of an exploit that was possible against lambdabot.

Since lambdabot uses GHC presumably this was a bug (or feature) of GHC making assumptions about class laws. Does anyone remember what those are? And has this ever (or could it possibly) happen acidentally?

(googling for "haskell +Evillx" turns up no hits).

Comment: Breaking the Typeable representation is a fairly compelling example. `instance Typeable Int where typeRep = "Bool"`

Comment: EvilIx: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2006-December/019994.html

Comment: Isn't Typeable the only class that can actually cause trouble?

Comment: @sclv: thank you for the EvilIx reference: I had had it spelled wrong! (darn font making l and I look the same). I like that example because it's terrible "normal" -- it's the exact same kind of security problem you'd get in C by not checking your indices.

Comment: @sclv,DonStewart you could post those as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays use `Ix` to manage bounds. They trust that `Ix` does what it says. If it doesn't, you can trick the array mechanisms into accessing memory locations that aren't theirs.

cf `EvilIx`: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2006-December/019994.html

Comment: This exploit does not work in GHC 7.6 anymore, I believe it was fixed but can't find a source.

Answer (score 4):

If we think of a monad as modelling side effects, a type claiming to be a monad but
not obeying the laws can result in effects occurring in the wrong order or the wrong
number of times.

A classic example of this is `ListT`, the list monad transformer.
The original implementation didn't satisy the monad laws.
The "[ListT Done Right](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right)
wiki page has some simple examples of usage of `ListT` in the section called
"[Examples](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ListT_done_right#Examples)".
You can see the difference between what these programs do
when you run them with the original
implementation that violates the laws, and
when you run them with a replacement that satisfies the laws.