# Member function doesn't work correctly for floating point numbers

Tags: haskell, floating-point, monads

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399798/124538) answer, the following code is evaluated as follows:

```
> let x = fromList  [0, -1, 0/0, -5, -6, -3] :: Set Float

> member 0 x
True

> let x' = insert (0/0) x

> member 0 x'
False
```

The author states the this happens because the `Eq` and `Ord` floating point instances don't obey the monad laws. How do the `Eq` and `Ord` floating point instances break the monad laws and why does that result in the behavior above?

Comment: Well just think of how the `Set` data type stores elements (sorted tree) and consider the fact that `let x = 0 / 0 :: Float in compare 0 x == compare x 0 -- both are GT`.  Makes it hard to find an element when you are looking at the wrong branch.

Comment: Given that allowing /0 makes arithmetic completely break down, it's hardly surprising that including it in your code leads to bugs. When your maths teacher said you couldn't divide by zero, they really meant it. ;)

Comment: For the record, the author actually states that floating point numbers don't obey the laws for Eq and Ord, not that they don't obey the monad laws. It was an analogy for why you shouldn't break laws; you introduce bugs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not the monad laws that are violated, but the laws for `Eq` with respect to `Ord`.

The laws on `Eq` demand that `(==)` define an equivalence relation,

```
forall x. x == x
forall x y. x == y <=> y == x
forall x y z. x == y && y == z => x == z
```

and the contract of `Ord` is that `<` define a total ordering,

```
forall x. not (x < x)
forall x y. (x < y) || (x == y) || (y < x)
forall x y. not (x < y && y < x)
```

The floating point types violate these laws because NaNs (NaN = Not a Number) compare unequal to themselves,

```
0/0 /= 0/0
```

and any comparison `<`, `<=`, ... involving a NaN returns `False`.

So when there are NaNs in a tree that is supposed to be ordered, a comparison with a NaN when searching for an element can send the recursive search down the wrong subtree.

Comment: Also, my `Data.Set` example in the linked answer was derived from the example in [this haskell-cafe message](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091866.html). The goofy results from `sort` and `minimum` perhaps demonstrate more clearly what's going wrong.